# value of $VAR already contains backtick and/or single quote inside. How to handle it? How to properly pass $VAR to program?

Tags: bash, find, variable, quoting, special-characters

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, versione 5.2.26(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I don't know how to deal with *$VAR* when its value inside contains single quote (`'`) and/or backtick (`` ` ``).

I'm in the need of executing *find*'s `-exec` based on entries found in `list.txt`.

`list.txt` contains:

- one *FILENAME.EXT* per line
- each line ends with *newline* (`\n`)

As a preventive test to verify everything is OK, I run these:

```
$ while IFS= read -r song; do find /mnt/EXTHDD/unsorted -type f -name "$song"; done < list.txt
```

```
$ while IFS= read -r song; do find /mnt/EXTHDD/unsorted -type f -name "*$song*"; done < list.txt
```

```
$ while IFS= read -r song; do find /mnt/EXTHDD/unsorted -type f -name '$song'; done < list.txt
```

```
$ while IFS= read -r song; do find /mnt/EXTHDD/unsorted -type f -name "${song}"; done < list.txt
```

None worked...

Unfortunately, not all occurrences are listed due to Special Characters in *FILENAME* and thus `$song` variable cannot be quoted correctly (neither with double quotes, nor single quotes).

Example of lines *FILENAME.EXT* found in `list.txt`:

```
Pino Daniele ~ [2000] Napul`e' - Raccolta completa ~ 01.14) `O ssaje comme fa `o core.mp3
```

```
[CONCERTI] Malora -- Live@TANT`E'! (Agosto '05, Villa Fossa` [presa diretta, mixer:stereo]) -- #15. 20:30 ... Tutto tace?.wave
```

Comment: I'd bet that the problem isn't the quotes. The problem is  the text in `[...]`, which is a shell glob, e.g., `[2000]` matches a `2` or `0`, `[CONCERTI]` matches `C`, `O`, `N`, `E`, `R`, `T` or `I`.

Comment: `"$song"` and `"${song}"` (and `"*$song*"`, if you want to pass asterisks) are properly quoted and the value of the variable cannot break them. Bash cannot store null bytes in a variable, but filenames (pathnames in general) also cannot contain null bytes, so this shouldn't be a problem in this usage case. AFAIK everything else can be stored in a variable. If your code does not work as expected, it's not because allegedly "the variable cannot be quoted correctly"; it can.

Comment: Too bad `find` doesn't have the equivalent of `grep -F`. Not even in GNU find, even though it supports various regex dialects via the `-regextype` option.

Comment: @muru I didn't know the exact `-name` (or `-iname`) behaviour in `find`; you're right, indeed. Thanks, dear!

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/773436/value-of-var-already-contains-backtik-and-or-single-quote-inside-how-to-handle#comment1477530_773436 yes! This helped me

Comment: Dear members all... Should I edit my question in order to clarify the actual issue? Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here are NOT single quote (`'`) and/or backtick (`` ` ``).

Rather, I needed to escape square brackets (`[` and `]`) in order to prevent *GNU find* interpreting values of `-name` (or `-iname`) as a *glob*.

Super thanks to [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) and [Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski) for pointing me to the right direction!

Here's how I solved with this *oneliner*:

```
while IFS= read -r song; do 
  unsquare=$(printf '%s\n' "$song" | sed 's/\[/\\[/g;s/\]/\\]/g') && 
   find /mnt/EXTHDD/unsorted -type f -name "$unsquare" 
done < list.txt
```

Comment: This is still a oneliner, I just split to multiple lines for clarity. You can still copy/paste directly into a terminal but this is much easier to read on this page than having it on a single line.